# Importing modules from file path very slow Is there any solution for this?

Tags: python-3.x, reflection, python-importlib

I have a list of modules that should be imported automatically and in a dynanamic way.
Here is a snippet from my code:

```
for m in modules_to_import:
    module_name = dirname(__file__)+ "/" +m
    spec = importlib.util.spec_from_file_location("package", module_name)
    imported_module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
    spec.loader.exec_module(imported_module)
```

I measured the time and it becomes slower and slower after each import. Is there some solution to this or why does it become slower? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Did you find any solution to this issue? I have about 20 modules to import and it takes about 1h n my system and also Google Colab!

Comment: Somehow it was solves. Not sure again how. But 1h is definitely way too long. I had more then 100 of modules and it took definitely less then an hour.

Comment: Humm, it is interesting that I did the same procedure one month ago and was fast. But now it's such slow. 
As a doubt, why did you used `importlib.import_module(item)` instead of your script? Is there any difference?

Answer (score 1):

I have not timed it but why dont you simplify your code. Looking at your code, you want to import module that are in the same directory as that file. By default, when you import a module, that the first place it look for.

First let's create some files to import all in the same directory:

**First.py**

```
def display_first():
    print("I'm first")
```

**Second.py**

```
def display_second():
    print("I'm second")
```

**Third.py**

```
def display_third():
    print("I'm third")
```

So one way to do it is putting your modules in a dict that you can use afterwards. I'm using here a dict comprehension here to build that dict:

**Solution1.py**

```
import importlib

modules_to_import = ["First", "Second", "Third"]

modules_imported = {x: importlib.import_module(x) for x in modules_to_import}

modules_imported["First"].display_first()
modules_imported["Second"].display_second()
modules_imported["Third"].display_third()
```

Or if you really want to use to use the dotted notation to access a module's content, your could use a [named tuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) to help:

**Solution2.py**

```
import importlib
import collections

modules_to_import = ["First", "Second", "Third"]

modules_imported = collections.namedtuple("imported_modules", modules_to_import)

for next_module in modules_to_import:
    setattr(modules_imported, next_module, importlib.import_module(next_module))

modules_imported.First.display_first()
modules_imported.Second.display_second()
modules_imported.Third.display_third()
```

Comment: My problem was that it becomes slower after each call of  importlib.import_module(x). Actually tried everything. Right now the solution is really ugly involving opening a subprocess and doing the stuff with that module. Seems to be a bug/issue in importlib.

Comment: How many modules do you have to import? And is it possible that these modules import other modules which would then take more time? How do you time it?